# Read variable contents

Tags: matlab, variables

I have a large number of variables uploaded to MATLAB workspace. Now I need to call them through a FOR loop, for example I need to call the variable VAR_10_V and read its content and do something with it. How can I do that?

Comment: Is there a particular pattern to the names of the variables of interest?

Comment: And where do the variables and their values come from?

Comment: What other variable do you want to call? `VAR_1_V`, `VAR_2_V`, etc. or what's the pattern?

Comment: Actually there is pattern for the variable name like VAR_1_V, VAR_2_V, VAR_3_V,.....

Answer (score 1):

A good practice in such cases is to load the variables, stored in a `'mat'`-file, as a struct (and not as independant variables)

```
ld = load( 'myMatFile.mat' ); % load into struct ld
varNames = fieldnames( ld ); % get the names of all variables
for ii = 1:numel( varNames )
    vn = varNames{ii}; % the variable name
    ld.(vn); % its value
    % do something with ld.(vn) here...
end
```